# Long running loop slows down?

Tags: python, loops, optimization, generator

I have a generator function in python which reads a dataset in chunks and yields each chunk in a loop. 
On each iteration of the loop, the chunk size is the same and the data array is overwritten.

It starts off by yielding chunks every ~0.3s and this slows down to every ~3s by about the 70th iteration. 
Here is the generator:

```
def yield_chunks(self):
  # Loop over the chunks
  for j in range(self.ny_chunks):
    for i in range(self.nx_chunks):         
      dataset_no = 0
      arr = numpy.zeros([self.chunk_size_y, self.chunk_size_x, nInputs], numpy.dtype(numpy.int32))

      # Loop over the datasets we will read into a single 'chunk'
      for peril in datasets.dataset_cache.iterkeys():
        group = datasets.getDatasetGroup(peril)
        for return_period, dataset in group:
          dataset_no += 1

          # Compute the window of the dataset that falls into this chunk
          dataset_xoff, dataset_yoff, dataset_xsize, dataset_ysize = self.chunk_params(i, j)

          # Read the data
          data = dataset[0].ReadAsArray(dataset_xoff, dataset_yoff, dataset_xsize, dataset_ysize)

          # Compute the window of our chunk array that this data fits into
          chunk_xoff, chunk_yoff = self.window_params(dataset_xoff, dataset_yoff, dataset_xsize, dataset_ysize)

          # Add the data to the chunk array
          arr[chunk_yoff:(dataset_ysize+chunk_yoff), chunk_xoff:(dataset_xsize+chunk_xoff), dataset_no] = data

      # Once we have added data from all datasets to the chunk array, yield it
      yield arr
```

Is it possible that memory is not being properly released after each chunk, and this is causing the loop to slow down? Any other reasons?

Comment: Could you provide some more of the class (e.g. chunk_params(), window_params()), and possibly an example of the dataset that you're using? I am suspicious of your innermost loop -- if any of those calls are linear-time (or more) with the size of their input, and the input gets any bigger, that would lead to your slowdown. I'd like to try to profile it.